# How to Read/Write a File With Multiple Unknown Size Record Structures

Tags: c

I am working on developing an application that can have user defined data fields on different UI Forms created by the user. My problem is how do I read/write those data records when I don't know the structure to create the "struct" code or data size it will be. The only information I would have is the field declaration information the user provided in order to possibly determine the record size, but that will vary as well given the length of the data.

User Defined Field:

```
Field Type: String (char *)
Field Name: fldFirstName
Field Caption: First Name
```

If the fields on Form 1 are: Name, Address, City, State and Zip. How do I create a dynamic record structure that can be used to read/write the data to/from a file.

```
struct _dynamic_ {
    char *Name;
    char *Address;
    char *City;
    char State[2];
    char Zip[10];
}
```

For clarity, I understand how to read/write files, but I haven't figured out how to resolve this issue without a given "struct" to define the data for each form the user creates. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is what XML, JSON, and other data exchange formats were invented for.

Comment: Your data definitions have pointers on the disk file.  Data pointers in a disk file are meaningless.  Suggest modifying the data definitions to have fixed maximum lengths (develop a struct definition that holds all the data (even if some disk space is wasted, disk space is (relatively) cheap)

Comment: If there are several different record formats on the disk, then suggest adding a field that selects which data format the current record contains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files (that is `FILE*` handles) from [`<stdio.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io)  don't have any record structures. They are just a stream of bytes. Even [fread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) is reading bytes (in some multiple of  given`size`), but *conventionally*, *you* could *decide* they are "records".

You need to define and specify on paper (or at least in some comment) your [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format). You might use [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation for that specification. Then you could use [recursive descent parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) techniques to read that file. You may prefer to use some [plain text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_text) format because it is easier to debug. Then you could read every line (with [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) or `getline`) and parse each of them (perhaps also having your [lexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)). Read about [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization), it is likely to be relevant.

Remember that computers are very fast, and RAM is always much faster than your disk (even if it is an SSD). You might prefer using *existing* textual formats such as [JSON](https://json.org/), [YAML](https://yaml.org/), XML because you'll easily find existing libraries to deal with these. Remember that the cost of data processing is quite often much smaller than the cost of I/O.

If [direct access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access#Direct_access) inside your file is a concern, consider using something like [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) or [GDBM](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/). It could be easier to code.

In many cases, the cost (or monetary value) of data is more important that the cost of the software handling it. Don't forget to backup your data.

I don't understand exactly your application, but I would recommend using [JSON](https://json.org/) or [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) in it, using *existing* appropriate libraries. Since your development time (and cost) matters a lot.

Of course, if your data is huge (e.g. much bigger than your RAM, so terabytes) you'll have different concerns and different approaches. Given your topic (some kind of data  about people; then you may be concerned about [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation) and you certainly have some ethical questions about such data, since it is unethical to collect data about persons without them knowing about data concerning them), it is unlikely: we are less than ten billion persons on earth, and each of your records is very probably less than 200 bytes, so all information about every living person fits on a single hard disk.

Be also aware of [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation). You probably need it.

PS. [Record-oriented files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record-oriented_filesystem) existed in the mainframe era (e.g. [MVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVS), [VMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS)) in the 1970s or 1980s. Current operating systems (read [*Operating Systems: three easy pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)) such as Linux, Windows, Unix, Android, MacOSX all provide a byte stream abstraction for their files and also [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)) in their [file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system). Many have [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database#Database_management_system) above that, or perhaps some kind of key-value abstraction (e.g. GDBM, [Kyoto Cabinet](https://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/), [REDIS](https://redis.io/), ...)